# Manually uninstall Microsoft Security Essentials (error 8007066F when uninstalling)

Tags: windows, uninstall, ms-security-essentials

When trying to uninstall Microsoft Security Essentials on Windows Vista x86 via Programs and Features, I got an error message, code 8007066F, with no description. How can I remove Security Essentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft published a [Fixit](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9748340) tool for this at [KB 2435760](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2435760). After running this, Security Essentials was removed, but I still needed to remove the executable from the startup list. I did this by going to `Start`-> *type in* `MSCONFIG` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Once the MSConfig tool started, I clicked on Startup, and unticked 'Microsoft Security Essentials' from the list.

[There is this Microsoft Fix It](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall) if the above link does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The above links didn't work for me, but the response [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/mse-protect_start/uninstall-security-essentials-for-windows-10/3317fffb-d4e9-49e2-aeae-7b9c4d5f22d3?page=14) by GlenDelport worked.

From the URL (with minor modifications):

- Browse to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\
- Locate the file Setup.exe, right click on it and choose properties
- Click on the Compatibility tab
- At the bottom of the tab click 'Change Settings for all users'
- On the next screen check the box for 'Run this program in compatibility mode for:' and choose Windows 7
- Click OK
- Click OK
- From the taskbar search box type cmd.exe and right click and choose 'Run As Administrator'. This will open an elevated command prompt as Administrator
- In the command prompt window copy/paste or type the following:

  ```
  cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client
  setup.exe /x /disableoslimit
  ```
- Choose to Uninstall
- Once this has finished, reboot and Microsoft Security Essentials will be gone and Windows Defender should be running correctly.

Comment: This post was for Windows Vista...

Comment: Oops. Well, I figure I'll leave this here for now in case anyone has this issue on Windows 10 and receives the 0x8004ff6f error. I'm not sure why I ran into this post and didn't realize it. I'll try to make a different question and delete this post later.